# NextJS and Prisma crashes without loading

Tags: next.js, prisma

I have developed a simple `schema.prisma` generated it, and can view it using `npx prisma studio`.
I run a local instance of `postgresql` in my MAC and it shows up correctly. When I try to make my first API endpoint `[PID].ts` like this:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

//http://localhost:3000/api/projects/lkasmdfm129

type Data = {
  project?: any; // Replace 'any' with your Project type
  error?: string;
};

console.log(prisma);
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
  // res: NextApiResponse
) {
  return res.status(200).json({ project: "hello" });
});
```

As soon as I hit `http://localhost:3000/api/projects/lkasmdfm129` on my browser, it freezes NextJS then I have to restart and kill port 3000 for it to work. If I remove these lines:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
console.log(prisma);
```

Then the page loads correctly. I have installed-uninstalled prisma, redone the schema, re-generated, did `npx prisma db push` and the rest to no avail.

Any ideas?